Clarke transform seems to result in more current
I am looking into the Clarke transform for a balanced three-phase system (BLDC motor) and from all that I read, it tries to preserve magnitude. So if I apply this to the case of transforming three phase motor current, the total current through the motor should be equal to the vector length of the uClarke vector. This generally seems true, but there seem to be edge cases where this does not hold. Take, for example:
$$
    i_a(t) = \sin(t) \\
    i_b(t) = \sin(t + \frac{2\pi}{3}) \\
    i_c(t) = \sin(t + \frac{4\pi}{3})
$$
If we look at \$t = 0\$, we get \$i_a(0) = 0\$, \$i_b(0) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\$ and \$i_c(0) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\$. So the total current through our system at \$t = 0\$ is \$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \$ Ampere.
But when applying the Clarke transformation at \$t = 0\$, we get
$$
    i_{\alpha\beta}(0)= \frac{2}{3}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
        0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
So the vector length of this Clarke transform is 1, which seemingly implies that there is 1A of current going through the system at \$t = 0\$.
This puzzles me. What is the physical interpretation of this? Or is current trough the system and vector length of Clarke transform unrelated?
